# How to programatically call executable in ruby

Tags: ruby, macos

I'm trying to dynamically call a program depending if a user has it installed or not

```
@program_path = %x(which x)
unless $?.success?
  #download program to a location
  #set path to above location
  @program_path = "$HOME/Downloads/location"
end
`#{@program_path} login -r #{HOST} -n #{NICKNAME} -u #{@username} -P #{@password}`
```

It runs properly when the program is not installed. 
But when it is installed it seems to not call the full program I have in backticks - like its missing the arguments? 
Similarly it doesn't work with %x either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

chomp!

@program_path = %x(which x).chomp